# CRUD with pg_featureserv

Tags: untagged

If one is to use pg_featureserv from Crunchydata for displaying features onm a webmap, what would be the best way to perform crud operastions? Is it at all posible to update info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in the docs POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE... TBD.  So no, updates are not possible with the pg_featureserv api but may be a work in progress.